# Windows API, C++: Is there a way to create a HANDLE to redirect output to a string using WriteFile()?

Tags: c++, winapi, base64

I have Base64 encoded data in the form of `const void*`. When I write the data to a file using the `WriteFile()` function, the data gets written in a correct format. However, when I try to print it by using `std::cout` (directly, or after typecasting it to `char*`), the format is different/undesired. So, I changed the `HANDLE` passed to the `WriteFile()` to print correct output to the console and it worked.

Is there any way to keep/redirect the equivalent data in a string(or char array)? I tried searching for a `HANDLE` to write the output to a string variable using the `WriteFile()`, but have been unsuccessful so far. Here's the code:

```
    void Write(const void* data, int size)
    {

        /* filePath is a local variable here */
        HANDLE mFile = CreateFileA(filePath, FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if ((mFile != NULL) && (size > 0))
        {
            std:: cout << data;                         // incorrect/undesired output
            char* stringData = (char *)data;
            std::cout << stringData;                    // incorrect/undesired output
            DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
            /* Writes output to the file */
            WriteFile(mFile, data, static_cast<DWORD>(size), &bytesWritten, NULL);

            /* Writes output to the console */
            HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            WriteFile(hStdOut, data, static_cast<DWORD>(size), &bytesWritten, NULL);

        }
    }
```

WriteFile() function:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _In_         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Here's the output required(base64 encoded):
[image]

And this is the output(incorrect/undesired) when we try to print the data directly using `std::cout`
[image]

Comment: Being not invalid, using the name `hStdIn` for *output* handle looks confusing.

Comment: @MikeCAT My bad. Should be hStdOut conventionally. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
std:: cout << data;
```

Prints the address passed because the type of `data` is `void*` (or precisely `const void*`).

```
char* stringData = (char *)data;
std::cout << stringData;
```

Requires the data to write NUL-terminated.

You can use [`write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function to put byte streams to `std::basic_ostream` (including `std::cout`).

```
std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), size);
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT. That works. But how do I write to a string, instead of the console?

Comment: @argcv [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) should be useful.

Comment: `(char *)` is a `const_cast` in disguise.

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT. `stringstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), size)` does the job. Is there an alternate way though? Some functions of the `std` library are disabled by my organization. One of them is `std::stringstream`. 

Please let me know if there's an alternative.

Comment: @arg `std::stringstream` is a type, not a function. Regardless, you can construct a [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from a pair of iterators (`data` and `data + size`), or even just a single pointer if the source is zero terminated. Though if your organization doesn't allow you to use C++, you should probably point that out in the question.

Comment: Thanks @llnspectable. I'll try this. The project is in C++, but as I mentioned, certain `std` library features are disabled, stringstream being one of them.

Comment: @argcv you can also construct a `std::string` directly from a `char*` and `size` too, eg: `std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), size);` Or, in C++17 and later, consider `std::string_view`

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.